# Is any other Tool Available to create Private keys and Certificate other than OpenSSL?

Tags: ssl, cryptography, certificate, private-key, pem

I need to create and test certificate and key generated by thrid party tool other tahn open ssl , IS any tool availiable to use free of cost ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few, for example:

- [Lib NSS's certutil](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tools/certutil.html)
- Java's `keytool`
- [TinyCA](http://tinyca.sm-zone.net/) (actually, a front-end to OpenSSL)

Some OS will also provide their own tool, for example, Apple's KeyChain.app can be used as a small Certification Authority tool.